# sass-loader 9.0.x & vue: ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object

Tags: vue.js, sass-loader, vue-loader

I recently upgraded my sass-loader from *8.0* to **9.0** and when I run `npm run build` (`vue-cli-service build`) I get this error

```
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options 
object that does not match the API schema.- options has an unknown property 'prependData'
```

The only occurence of the word `prependData` is in my `vue.config.js`:

```js
{
  //...
  publicPath: process.env.VUE_APP_ASSETS_PUBLIC_PATH,
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: { // \/\/\/\/ here's prependData below
        prependData: `
            @import "~@salesforce-ux/design-system/design-tokens/dist/theme-one-salesforce.default.scss";
          `
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change `prependData` in `vue.config.js` to `additionalData`.

More info in [the changelog for vue-loader 9.0.0](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v9.0.0):

> - the prependData option was removed in favor the additionalData option, see [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#additionaldata)

The [`vue-loader` guide](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sharing-global-variables) recommends additionalData now aswell.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this issue. I've made a [pull request with vue-loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/pull/1714).